# Does a raspberry pi VPN do anything?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi

Does a raspberry pi vpn do anything besides hide your traffic on your local network? Can your ISP still see what traffic you are sending? Are homebrew openvpn raspberry pi vpn servers a viable source of internet privacy (ex. keeping your ISP from selling your personal information?)

Comment: We need more information about exactly how this is set up to say anything. Where is the pi? Lan? Friends house? at a McDonalds? How do you connect to it? Does it exist within the same ISP as well? etc...

Comment: It would be setup using your own home internet that you pay for (ex. time warner, comcast, etc.) It is connected to the same home network as your laptop through ethernet. You would connect to it using the same network and sometimes at an internet cafe (which would be a good usage as it would travel through SSL to your home network.) Is it practical within home network usage to keep your ISP from using your data for profit?

Answer (score 2):

> Does a raspberry pi vpn do anything besides hide your traffic on your local network?

When it's on your local network, it can not.

> Can your ISP still see what traffic you are sending? Are homebrew openvpn raspberry pi vpn servers a viable source of internet privacy (ex. keeping your ISP from selling your personal information?)

Only when you put your raspberry on some other network where the internet connection is not provided by your ISP. That way you have an encrypted tunnel to the raspberry. However, the ISP which provides internet connectivity to *that* network can monitor unencrypted traffic routed through the Raspberry.

---

In general, the idea behind "VPN for anonymous internet use" is that someone you trust to respect your privacy provides a VPN with an internet gateway which is 1. connected to the internet through a privacy-friendly ISP and 2. is used by so many people that no connection can be reliably matched to a specific user.